Why does GAP at the end of FCN for MTSC work?
I have a binary MTSC (Multivariate Time Series Classification) problem where i train a CNN, namely a FCN (or Fully Convolutional Network) to predict class 0 or class 1 based on a multivariate time series. The MTS contains 57 different features, all 24 long, resulting in a 57 x 24 array.
I have taken inspiration from this paper where they use a 3-convolution stack with 128, 256 and 128 filters respectively, and end with a GAP layer (Global Average Pooling).
The forwarding the works like this: The 57 x 24 array containing 57, 24 long series, is arranged so that the features come as channels into the first layer. 128 1d feature maps are created, from that 256 new ones, and then 128 final ones. This results in a 128 x 24 array. The GAP layer is applied, shrinking the array in the second dimension by taking the mean, and returning a 128 long vector. The vector is then fed into a fully connected layer which makes the prediction through a sigmoid function.
My question is: why does it work to put a GAP layer at the end of the network? What is the logic/intuition behind it? I can not make sense of it.

...i would suggest you to stop using acronyms that are definitely not standard/widely used...

What acronyms are you referring to?
